# uv unwrapping a tire for a game

Tags: texturing, uv

is it possible to use cylinder project and instead of one continuous uv split it into even sections?
I could brute force it and do it manually with seams, but im pretty sure i got it to work automatically sometime before and forgot.
ive attached a gif to further explain what im trying to accomplish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hit  <kbd>U</kbd>  to call unwrap menu in 3d viewport, choose Cylinder Projection:

[image]

This operator is not the best design, since it doesn't let you specify how the cylinder is supposed to be rotated, so if you have random rotation of the mesh, it will not work. In that case, simple unwrapping is the way to go. You need a seam across the tire so  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Click</kbd>  on one edge at the start and another at the end to select the shortest path between them and hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>E</kbd>   ->   <kbd>M</kbd>  to mark as seam:

[image]

Now you need to straighten the UVs. You could do that manually, but there is this [UvSquares](https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares) add-on that can do it for you in one click. You would need to install and enable it following the instructions in the link(installation is standard as with any other add-on). It requires quads, so you would need to convert tris to quads first in your case(select all hit  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>J</kbd> ). With your geometry this should work perfectly. Then just select all UVs and hit To Grid by Shape in the Sidebar of the UV Editor, the add-on's tab:

[image]